why absolute path gets BlocProvider related error in flutter?
when I use the following code snippet in flutter
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/features/note/presentation/screens/note_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/features/note/presentation/screens/create_note.dart';

class Routes {
   static Map<String, WidgetBuilder> getRoutes() {
    return {
      '/': (context) => const NoteList(),
      '/create': (context) => const CreateNote(),
    };
  }
}


I get this issue

but when I remove absolute path from the code snippet issue gets resolved

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../features/note/presentation/screens/note_list.dart';
import '../features/note/presentation/screens/create_note.dart';

class Routes {
   static Map<String, WidgetBuilder> getRoutes() {
    return {
      '/': (context) => const NoteList(),
      '/create': (context) => const CreateNote(),
    };
  }
}


I tried to use relative path and and fixed the issue.

you should provide code where CounterBloc is created

Hello @VladyslavUlianytskyi, what did you mean?

on the error screen there is CounterBloc. how do you create tthe instance of CounterBloc and where? - that what I mean
